# cannot open microsoft.office.interop.word

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

i am trying to open a word document but its not working. i can only save the document, what could be the problem?

```
 object missing = Missing.Value;
 object start1 = 0;

 var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

 var myDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

 object doNotSaveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
 Range rng = myDoc.Range(ref start1, ref missing);

 try
 {
    const char newLine = (char)11;
    myDoc.SaveAs(ref fs,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
             ref missing,
             ref missing,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
     myDoc.Save();

     myDoc.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);

     wordApp.Quit(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myDoc);   
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
    GC.Collect();
```

Comment: where is the code for opening the document where you're having problems with

Comment: "its not working" is not at all a helpful description of any kind of a problem. If you problem is with opening a file then why are you showing us the code that you have for saving a file?

Comment: because i first save the file to the root then i want the user to choose if he want to open it or save it on his desktop?

Comment: Word experienced an error trying to opet the file.
Try these sugesstions.
*Check the file permissions for the document or drive
*Make sure there is suffient free memory and disk space.
*Open the file with the text recovery convert

Comment: and if i self dont now why its not working i should i explain it?

Comment: i solved it by my self, my codes looks perfect it ways a setting inside word i needed to change..